# Program fails on AWS EMR with hadoop (OK on local machine)

Tags: python, hadoop, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to use python's [fuzzywuzzy package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) in mapper program for computing edit distance. My program runs fine on local machine but it fails on AWS emr cluster. I tried below two approaches(on both local machine and also on AWS EMR cluster):

**1. By installing fuzzywuzzy:**

I installed fuzzywuzzy using pip on both master and slave nodes. If I comment out last 4 lines of below code, I do not get any error. But I want to use fuzzywuzzy in my program.

```
!/usr/bin/python  
import re
import sys
import os
import csv

desc_dict = {}
with open('Keys.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
            query_set = row

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip() 
  row = line.split(',')
  if(len(row)>2):
      desc_dict[(int(row[0]), row[1])] = (row[2].lower()).encode('utf-8')
from fuzzywuzzy import *
import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz
import fuzzywuzzy.utils
print fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.partial_ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
```

I get below error:

```
 Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

**2. Without installing fuzzywuzzy**

I could run  above map-reduce program without installing fuzzywuzzy on local machine. When I tried the same on AWS EMR it failed.

I zipped fuzzywuzzy package ("temp.zip") and called it in my map program. I copied temp.zip file to slave nodes also.

!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    import sys
    import os
    import csv

```
desc_dict = {}
with open('Keys.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
            query_set = row

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip() 
  row = line.split(',')
  if(len(row)>2):
      desc_dict[(int(row[0]), row[1])] = (row[2].lower()).encode('utf-8')

sys.path.insert(0,'temp.zip')
from fuzzywuzzy import *
import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz
print fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.partial_ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
```

I get below error:

```
 Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

Can someone guide what is wrong with my code/ how to run fuzzywuzzy on hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

I could get fuzzywuzzy working by copying fuzzywuzzy install files to master and slave nodes and then install fuzzywuzzy manually

```
python setup.py install
```

pip install did not install fuzzywuzzy even though it was successful.